# Implemented Bluebird nested loops promise in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I'm using bluebird in NodeJS. I want to do a nested loop. Something like this:

```
  var Promise = require('bluebird');

  funcs.getLatestVideos = function(job, done) {
              return Promise.try(function() {
                      return ProcessRules.getLatestVideos();
                  })
                  .then(function(object) {
                      return ({
                          'series': ProcessRules.getSeriesRules(),
                          'videos': object.videos
                      });
                  })
                  .then(function(inputs) {
                      return Promise.map(inputs.videos, function(video) {
                          return Promise.map(inputs.series, function(series) {
                              return Promise.map(series.rules, function(rule) {
                                  return ProcessRules.processRules(video, rule);
                              });
                          });
                      })
                  })
                  .then(function(result) {
                      W.debug("done");
                      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                      done();
                  })
                  .catch(function(err) {
                      done(err);
                      W.error("Error occurred ", err.message, err.stack);
                  });
   }
```

**ProcessRules**

```
     var Promise = require('bluebird');
     var rp = require('request-promise');
     var W = require('winston');
     var RuleEngine = require('node-rules');
     var _ = require('lodash');

          funcs.getSeriesRules = function() {
              return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                  var options = {
                      method: "GET",
                      uri: API_URL,
                      // body: status,
                      json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
                  };

                  rp(options)
                      .then(function(result) {
                          resolve(result)
                      })
                      .catch(function(err) {
                          reject(err)
                      });
              });
          };

            funcs.processRules = function(fact, rule) {
                return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    var rules = [];
                    var value = new RegExp(rule.value, 'i');

                    switch (rule.type) {
                        case 'title':
                            rules = [{
                                "condition": function(R) {
                                    //  console.log(this.title.match(value));
                                    R.when(this.title.match(value) > -1);
                                },
                                "consequence": function(R) {
                                    this.result = false;
                                    this.video = R;
                                    R.stop();
                                }
                            }];
                            break;
                        case 'desc':
                            rules = [{
                                "condition": function(R) {
                                    //console.log(this.desc.match(value));
                                    R.when(this.desc.match(value) > -1);
                                },
                                "consequence": function(R) {
                                    this.result = false;
                                    this.video = R;
                                    R.stop();
                                }
                            }];
                            break;
                        case 'tag':
                            rules = [{
                                "condition": function(R) {
                                    //  console.log(this.tag.match(value));
                                    R.when(!_.some(this.tags, { 'text': rule.value}))
                                },
                                "consequence": function(R) {
                                    this.result = false;
                                    this.video = R;
                                    R.stop();
                                }
                            }];
                            break;
                        default:
                            break
                    };

                    //initialize the rule engine
                    const R = new RuleEngine(rules);

                    //Now pass the fact on to the rule engine for results
                    R.execute(fact, function(result) {
                        //console.log(result);
                        if (result.result) {
                            resolve(result._id)
                        }else{
                          resolve({})
                        }
                    });
                });

            };
```

It returns me following output

```
  [[[{},{},"58e9d6816961c30367b5154c"],[{}],[],[],[]],[[{},{},"58e9d6816961c30367b5154d"],[{}],[],[],[]]]
```

But I am expecting with following output:

```
 [58e9d6816961c30367b5154c,58e9d6816961c30367b5154d]
```

I see some similar question but not getting exact ideas from them.

In `getLatestVideos` function  not able to get done result ,Please help me to resolve this issue.

Please help me to implement nested each loop with bluebird promise.

Comment: Where is your promise-returning function?

Comment: You seem to be looking for `Promise.map`. Please try something.

Comment: Yes I tried that one but it's not work properly

Comment: Show us your attempt, please, and tell us what part did not work as expected.

Comment: @Bergi I have updated the code

Comment: Do `ProcessRules.getLatestVideos()` and `ProcessRules.processRules()` return promises?  They need to return promises BEFORE you can use Bluebird with them.  Then, for us to help you further, we need to know (in your words) what you're trying to accomplish - what exact result you're trying to get to.

Comment: Yes I have return promises with them

Comment: @SantoshShinde - Are you sure those promises are resolving with proper values?  You need to do some of your own debugging to see where things get stuck.  Insert `console.log()` statements throughout your code and see how it executes. Or insert breakpoints at each step and inspect the progress at each one.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do with `Promise.each()` because it does not accumulate any kind of result for you.  It just resolves to the original array that was passed to it.  As others have said, perhaps you want `Promise.map()` if you want to accumulate an array of results.  But, since you don't describe in words what the input data is or what result you're trying to achieve, we can't really help you fix your program logic.  We'd have to know what you're trying to accomplish, what data you start with and what each of your functions do in order to help find the right code with detail.

Comment: If `getSeriesRules` does return a promise as well, you need to use `Promise.props` on the object before continuing

Comment: Yeah, You shoud handle ProcessRules.getSeriesRules() rejected promise.

Comment: @jfriend00  I have updated my questions with code , Please take a look and please let me know my mistake

Comment: The output you posted, where are you getting it? I don't see any console in your code. And please add `input` object value. What's in it when you start iterating over it?

Comment: In done section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search with multiple questions and answers , I got the answer by [Flattening a Promise map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809197/flattening-a-promise-map).

I don't know exactly its right way but its working for me.

```
            .then(function(inputs) {
                return Promise.map(inputs.videos, function(video) {
                    return Promise.map(inputs.series, function(series) {
                        return Promise.map(series.rules, function(rule) {
                            return ProcessRules.processRules(video, rule);
                        }).reduce(function(prev, cur) {
                            return cur ? prev.concat(cur) : [];
                        }, [])
                    }).reduce(function(prev, cur) {
                        return prev.concat(cur);
                    }, [])
                }).reduce(function(prev, cur) {
                    return prev.concat(cur);
                }, [])
            })
```

It returns me `[58e9d6816961c30367b5154c,58e9d6816961c30367b5154d]`.

Thanks Everyone.